# SQL Server Multiple DDLs Ignoring Order And in a Single Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ddl

I'm trying to run multiple DDLs (around 90) on an SQL Server.

The DDLs don't contain any changes to tables, only view, stored procedures, and functions. The DDLs might have inter-dependencies between them, one STP that calls another, for example.

I don't want to start organizing the files in the correct order, because it would take too long, and I want the entire operation to fail if any one of the scripts has an error.

How can I achieve this?

My idea so far, is to start a transaction, tell the SQL to ignore errors (which I don't know how to do) run all the scripts once, tell the SQL to start throwing errors again, run all the scripts again, and then commit if everything succeeds.

1. Is this a good idea?
2. How do I `CREATE \ ALTER` a stored procedure or view even though it has errors?

---

To clarify and address some concerns...

This is not intended for production. I just don't want to leave the DB I'm testing on broken.

What I would like to achieve is this: run a big group of scripts on the server, without taking the time to order them. But if any of the scripts has an error in it, I want to rollback the entire operation.

I don't care about isolation, I only want the operation to happen as a single transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually do something like this to deploy our database scripts to production. We do this in an application that connects to our databases. To add to the complication, we also have 600 databases that should have the same schema, but don't really. Here's our approach:

1. Merge all our scripts into one big file. Injecting go's in between every single file. This makes it look like there's one very long script. We do a simple ordering based on what the coders requested.
2. Split everything into "go blocks". Since go isn't legal sql, we split them up into multiple blocks that get executed one at a time.
3. Open a database connection.
4. Start a transaction.
5. for each go block:

   1. Make sure the transaction is still active. (This is VERY important. I'll explain why in a bit.)
   2. Run the code, recording the errors.
6. If there were any errors, rollback. Otherwise, commit.

In our multi database set up, we do this whole thing twice. Run through every database once, "testing" the code to make sure there are no errors on any database, and then go back and run them again "for real".

Now on to why you need to make sure the transaction is still active. There are some commands that will rollback your transaction on error! Imagine our surprise the first time we found this out... Everything before the error was rolled back, but everything after was committed. If there is an error, however, nothing in that same block gets committed, so it's all good.

Below is our core of our execution code. We use a wrapper around SqlClient, but it should look very similar to SqlClient.

```
Dim T = New DBTransaction(client)
For Each block In scriptBlocks
    If Not T.RestartIfNecessary Then
        exceptionCount += 1
        Log("Could not (re)start the transaction for {0}. Not executing the rest of the script.", scriptName)
        Exit For
    End If
    Debug.Assert(T.IsInTransaction)
    Try
        client.Text = block
        client.ExecNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        exceptionCount += 1
        Log(ex.Message + " on {0} executing: '{1}'", client.Connection.Database, block.Replace(vbNewLine, ""))
    End Try
Next
If exceptionCount > 0 Then Log("There were {0} exceptions while executing {1}.", exceptionCount, scriptName)
If testing OrElse
    exceptionCount > 0 Then
    Try
        T.Rollback()
        Log("Rolled back all changes for {0} on {1}.", scriptName, client.Connection.Database)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Log("Could not roll back {0} on {1}: {2}", scriptName, client.Connection.Database, ex.Message)
        If Debugger.IsAttached Then
            Debugger.Break()
        End If
    End Try

Else
    T.Commit()
    Log("Successfully committed all changes for {0} on {1}.", scriptName, client.Connection.Database)
End If
Return exceptionCount




Class DBTransaction
    Private _tName As String
    Public ReadOnly Property name() As String
        Get
            Return _tName
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _client As OB.Core2.DB.Client
    Public Sub New(client As OB.Core2.DB.Client, Optional name As String = Nothing)
        If name Is Nothing Then
            name = "T" & Guid.NewGuid.ToString.Replace("-", "").Substring(0, 30)
        End If
        _tName = name
        _client = client
    End Sub
    Public Function Begin() As Boolean
        Return RestartIfNecessary()
    End Function
    Public Function RestartIfNecessary() As Boolean
        Try
            _client.Text = "IF NOT EXISTS (Select transaction_id From sys.dm_tran_active_transactions where name = '" & name & "') BEGIN BEGIN TRANSACTION " & name & " END"
            _client.ExecNonQuery()
            Return IsInTransaction()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
    Public Function IsInTransaction() As Boolean
            _client.Text = "Select transaction_id From sys.dm_tran_active_transactions where name = '" & name & "'"
            Dim scalar As String = _client.ExecScalar
            Return scalar <> ""
    End Function
    Public Sub Rollback()
        _client.Text = "ROLLBACK TRANSACTION " & name
        _client.ExecNonQuery()
    End Sub
    Public Sub Commit()
        _client.Text = "COMMIT TRANSACTION " & name
        _client.ExecNonQuery()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I've started writing an F# script that does something similar... I'll probably post the source sometime...

Answer (score 4):

Organize the files in the correct order, test the procedure on a test environment, have a validation and acceptance test, then run it in production.

While running DDL in a transaction may seem possible, in practice is not. There are many DDL statements that don't mix well with transactions. You must put the application offline, take a database backup (or create a snapshot) before the schema changes, run the tested and verified upgrade procedure (your scripts), validate the result with acceptance tests and then turn the application back online. If something fails, revert to the backup created initially (with all the implications vis-a-vis any downstream log consumer like replication, log shipping or mirroring).

This is the correct way, and as far as I'm concerned the only way. I know you'll find plenty of advice on how to do this the wrong way.

Comment: Absolutely; another thing is that SQL Server won't throw an error at your DDL even if it references nonexisting column, if your object isn't schemabound. This is not SQL Server configuration-related stuff.  See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx), schemabindnig paragraph.

Comment: This is for the test environment... I'm just trying not to ruin the environment while making sure the scripts are ok...

Comment: Also i know DDL don't work with snapshot isolation, and all the ALTER DATABASE statements don't work with transaction. I just want to rollback the changes, if they fail...

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić If I take a view, and try to alter it with a non existing column, the command fails with "Msg 207"

Comment: @AK_ this was in general. CREATE/ALTER view will fail at the time referenced column is missing. CREATE/ALTER SP won't fail at the time whole referenced table is missing. As a matter of fact you can perform DROP COLUMN on table and leave your view that references it in 'corrupted' state without having any clue about that. As long as object is not schemabound.

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić Thank you, I've already experienced this :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a good answer, here is "hack" answer. For the case "You cannot do this, but if you want it very much, then go on". I'm quite confident that you will not achieve what you are thinking of, therefore

**DO FULL BACKUP!**

Assuming there are no `COMMIT` or `GO` statements (explicit or !implicit!) in any of these files, the only thing you need to do is to run them in a single transaction. Combine them in one file, wrap in a transaction, and run.

How to combine 90 files in 1 file:

If sorting by name brings them in right order, then run this from folder with files in command prompt:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1" %G IN ('dir /b /-d /o:n *.sql') DO (
    type %G >> Big_SQL_Script.sql && echo. >> Big_SQL_Script.sql 
    )
```

If order is random, then create a list of files `dir /b /-d *.sql > File_Name_List.txt` and order it manually. Then run:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1" %G IN (File_Name_List.txt) DO (
    type %G >> Big_SQL_Script.sql && echo. >> Big_SQL_Script.sql 
    )
```

This way you can concatenate 90 files in automated order. Run and see what happens.

Good luck!